# Evaluating Ruby code within the context of another Ruby script

Tags: ruby

My qustion is a lot easier to explain if you take a look at [this Github project](https://github.com/c00lryguy/inline_testing).

Basically `file1` tells `file2` the current line number, then `file2` reads the next couple of lines. Now I want to `eval` the code gathered in `file2` within the context of `file1`.

Any ideas? I don't expect anyone to code for me, but a nudge in the right direction would certainly help me out!

Comment: "next couple of lines" is too vague. How much do you need to read from `file1'? Which part is "code gathered in `file2`"?

Comment: `file1` also sends a method to `file2` that says the line number to stop gathering code at. Checkout the github project, it's only two small files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `eval` you need to get the [binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Binding.html) of the context.

Comment: Thank you! The code now works! It's quite functionless at the moment but the guts are there =)